# Get current ApplicationUser in a PartialView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

New MVC 5 project has _LoginPartial that display current username:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", 
                 "Manage", 
                 "Account", 
                 routeValues: null, 
                 htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

I have added last/first name fields to ApplicationUser class, but can't find a way to display them instead of UserName. Is there a way to access ApplicationUser object? I have tried straightforward casting `(ApplicationUser)User` but it generates bad cast exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In MVC5, `Controller.User` and `View.User`, returns are `GenericPrincipal` instance:

   ```
   GenericPrincipal user = (GenericPrincipal) User;
   ```
2. `User.Identity.Name` has username, you can use it to retrieve the `ApplicationUser`
3. C# has nice feature of extension methods. Explore and experiments with it.

**Use below as example** that cover some understanding for current question.

```
public static class GenericPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static ApplicationUser ApplicationUser(this IPrincipal user)
    {
        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = (GenericPrincipal)user;
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<Models.ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        if (userPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return userManager.FindById(userPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to use it without GenericPrincipal, cause that cast throws bad cast exception.

Comment: @Sergi0 too bad you don't share your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I did it!

Using the help in this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1994249.aspx?How+to+who+in+my+_LoginPartial+cshtml+all+the+rest+of+the+information+of+the+user

I did it like that:

In the AcountController, add an action to get the property you want:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public string GetCurrentUserName()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.GetUserName());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And in the _LoginPartialView, change the original line to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + @Html.Raw(Html.Action("GetCurrentUserName", "Account")) + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: if you have a feature, let's say ChangeUserName in a different partial in a different view, but sharing the same layout, will the _LoginPartialView update if the data changes?

Comment: If I understand your question, you will have to do some ajax to update the view. My solution requires a load of the page.